# HTML + Jquery dynamically adding bootstrap dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-4

I have a small question.

Building a system to manage bookings. Now I would like each booking to have its own individual dropdown menu.

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    All of my lovely actions
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="?add_booking_queue&id={booking_id}">Add to queue</a>
    <span class="dropdown-item" onclick="show_booking_summary({booking_id});">Another action</span>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="?download_pdf&id={booking_id}">Download booking PDF</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Some code just like this.

But in case I have about 1000 bookings listed in a single screen. This would generate such a load of HTML that it would work against me in loading time. And it would probably increase browser memory usage.

Now I would like to have this dropdown menu to be dynamically added.

For example adding a single button with this feature

```
<tr>
    <td>ticket : 293823098</td>
    <td>price : $59,-</td>
    <td>name : Donald Trump</td>
    <td><i class="fas fa-cog booking-action" data-id="238232"></i></td>
</tr>
```

Then when clicking on the .booking-action it adds the mentioned above dropdown. Or similar.  Not restricted to. Just as a reference. And using the set **data-id="238232"** / or another tag that contains just this.

My problem is that I seem not to be able to find the code or start required to realise this.
All I am finding are right-click context menu's and that's not what I am after.

Comment: In case you've a huge number of records, why not use pagination and show a limited number of records at a time?

Comment: Well the reason is that the client wants this also without pagination. I am offering a pagination option. But also without. But left or right the most elegant solution would be a dynamically added menu on click